# VMware broken after Windows 11 update

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I've used VMware Workstation Pro 16.1.1 to run a Mac OS Big Sur on windows 10 and after upgrading to Windows 11 I got this error:

[image]

I've tried:

~ Disable/Enable HyperV

~ Disable/Enable SVM Mode (AMD visualization in BIOS)

~ Repair VMware from install

~ Create a new Machine

~ Uninstall BitDefender Agent (default on Windows 11)

and none of those work.

Comment: This is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you enable AMD-V?

Try going through this guide ([Enable Virtualization in Windows 11](https://techrechard.com/how-to-enable-virtualization-in-windows-11/)) and see if it works.